# Will the reference word "they" cause confusion in my sentence?

Tags: writing, reference

As I write the following sentence, I am wondering whether it will cause confusion:

> Don't trust those who leave their friends the moment **they** get into difficulties.

Based on the meaning, I guess readers can interpret "they" as a reference to "their friends," but then I am worried about it could be understood referring to "those."

Idk, will it cause confusion? If so, what are some better variation?

Comment: I think the meaning is clear. Any attempt to clarify would probably mean a complete rewrite.

Comment: Most people would interpret it the way you intend. But the sentence is inherently ambiguous. To be certain: **Don't trust those who leave their friends the moment the latter get into difficulties.**